# Vue Js text inputs inside v-for all return same input

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a text input inside a v-for loop as follows. I want each text input to be filled uniquely but the following code when I type in one text input, all return the same value. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div v-for="(property, index) in properties" :key="index">
   <input type="text" v-model="form.property_name">Property name<br>
</div>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {

data() {
    return {
        form: {
            property_name: []
        }
    }
},

}
```

Comment: Where is 'properties' in your v-for defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above question, I am assuming this is the output you are expecting in form

```
form = {
  property_name: ["sas", "1`11"]
}
```

Replace your v-model with v-model="form.property_name[index]"

```
<div v-for="(property, index) in properties" :key="index">
   <input type="text" v-model="form.property_name[index]">Property name<br>
</div>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {

 data() {
    return {
        form: {
            property_name: []
        }
    }
 },

}
```

Comment: Note that if `properties` is an object and not an array, the `index` will return the key: in that case, `property_name` is better of an object, too.